# Freemarker function with parameter that can be empty

Tags: java, freemarker

I created function in Freemarker:

```
<#function formatDate anyDate>
    <#assign dateFormat = read_from_configuration() />
    <#if anyDate??>
        <#return anyDate?date(dateFormat) />
    <#else >
        <#return '' />
    </#if>
</#function>
```

I call it like this: `${formatDate(object.someDate)}`.

It all works until `someDate` is null. In that case I get exception:

```
Error executing macro: formatDate
required parameter: anyDate is not specified.
```

How can I do this? I want the function to work if parameter values is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end I did it like this:

```
<#function formatDate anyDate='notSet'>
    <#assign dateFormat = read_from_configuration() />
    <#if anyDate?is_date>
        <#return anyDate?string(dateFormat) />
    <#else >
        <#return '' />
    </#if>
</#function>
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's what I did, which seems to work in most scenarios:

The default value should be an **empty string**, and the null-check should be **?has_content**.

```
<#function someFunction optionalParam="" >
    <#if (optionalParam?has_content)>
        <#-- NOT NULL -->
    <#else>
        <#-- NULL -->
    </#if>
</#function>
```

Answer (score 2):

Freemarker doesn't really handle the null values very well.

I always use the ?has_content on the params to check if there is something in there. The other parameter checkers don't always handle the null value well either so I would suggest something like this:

```
<#if anyDate?has_content && anyDate?is_date>
```

just to be sure.

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't even go inside the function when parameter is empty. It just throws the exception when invoking the function. Those checks will not be called.